# Which deity should be prayed or which mantra can be recited, while flying in an aircraft?

Tags: gods, mantras, culture

Sometimes while a flight takes off, I become nervous. I would like to know which *mantra* to recite or which deity to invoke.
I know to remove fear of water while travelling in water one may chant `शं नो वरुणः`.

Comment: The Vishnu Shodasha Nama Stotra prescribes 'Pravaase Cha Trivikramam' - Think of Lord Trivikrama during journeys. Since flight is also a form of journey maybe it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, the same Stotra also prescribes 'Jalamadhye Varaham cha' - Think of Varaha when amidst waters.

Comment: @Surya Pravase means " when you are in a foreign land"

Comment: @Rickross Oh thanks for the correction. Then will 'Gamane Vaamanam Caiva' (Think of Vamana while travelling) fit the description of a journey?

Comment: Yes that fits... But that applies to all kinds of journeys.. As OP says while traveling through water he thinks one should chant a Vedic mantra for Varuna. But according to the verse you have given one should think of Vamana in that case too.@Surya

Comment: Hanuman. Shri Hanuman is God of Winds. He is called Son of God of Winds Vaayu. We all know how Hanumaan travelled great distances flying.

Comment: But, most importantly, you must chant name of your IshtaDevata. Your IshtaDevata is your protector and also is form of all other Gods. Essentially there is no difference in any God, but we have to chose any one form of God as Ishta, who takes care of us forever and in any and every circumstances whatsoever. So you have faith in your Ishta, your Ishta will save you always.

Comment: Why different deity for different occasion? Always chant name of your aaradhya only. Dividing your faith in different Gods will decrease you chances of attaining Lord. Make focus only on one God and pray and ask for help from only one God. For me Rama is everything. Where ever I am, which ever trouble I got, I always ask Rama for help and keep remeber Rama only.